# Simple: Passing PHP var into SQL fails MySqli query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After reading through stackoverflow for a few hours and trying various suggestions I can't seem to get a simple sql statement to work.

I am using the latest XAMPP localhost with Apache for PHP and MySQL.

-------------------Table---------------

### id |   name    | transaction |

### 1  |  David    | 1234V       |

In PhpMyAdmin, the following non variable sql returns 1 rows. However, the variable sql returns a nonfunctional resource.

I've tried various re-arrangements of the sql statement and syntaxes for the $mysqli->query();

Am I missing something in php.ini or something?

```
$text = "here we have a long string of text with transaction ID: 1234V and some other stuff mixed in here.";

//lets cutup the string and only extract the transaction id
$array = explode("transaction ID: ", $text);

if (isset($array[1]))
    $array = explode("and", $array[1]);

$variable = $array[0]; //$array[0] = '1234V ';
$trans = "SELECT * FROM `name` WHERE `transaction` = '$variable';";

if($statement = $mysqli->prepare("$trans")){
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($id,$name,$transaction);

    while ($statement->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n",$id,$name,$transaction);
    }

    $statement->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
die();
```

This new code with the $variable printed this:

```
$trans = "SELECT * FROM `name` WHERE `transaction` = '$variable';";
mysqli_result 

Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )
```

and the new code with hardcode printed this:

```
$trans = "SELECT * FROM `name` WHERE `transaction` = '1234V ';";
mysqli_result

Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

Comment: Is there meant to be a space at the end of `1234V`?

Comment: And is there a missing close } for the `if ($mysqli->connect_error) {`?

Comment: If there were an imbalanced `{` then the PHP script wouldn't run at all. It would be a fatal error on parsing the file, and would return a 500 http status. I suggest you check your error log.

Comment: Yes, there is a space in the database value.

Comment: If you've done a cursory amount of reading on SO, you should know that dumping variables into a database query is terribly insecure. Use a prepared statement and that will probably solve your issue.

Comment: I found that if I change $trans = $passed[variable] to $trans = "1234V " the statement works. I therefore print_r($passed), only to see $passed[variable] = "1234V "

I will also check and change to use the bind_param

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: When you say _returns a nonfunctional resource_, is that literally what the output says or are those your words. Is it possible that your database connection failed?

Comment: It connects and outputs this:
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )

Comment: if that is variable then it should be `$passed($variable)` or if its a key then `$passed['variable']`

Comment: even if i flatten the variable/array into $variable ="1234V ", using the variable in the sql causes 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this:

```
$trans = "SELECT * FROM `name` WHERE `transaction` = ?";
```

Also, I think you should try thus:

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($trans);
$statement->bind_param("s", $passed[variable]);
$statement->execute();
if(...
```

Comment: Oh ... I think you have to bind. I will edit the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
$trans = "SELECT id, name, transaction FROM `name` WHERE `transaction` = ? ;";

if($statement = $mysqli->prepare($trans)){
    echo 'Let\'s check we are in? '.$passed['variable']."\n";
    $statement->bind_param("s", $passed['variable']);

    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($id, $name, $transaction);

    while ($statement->fetch()) {
        printf("FETCHED: %s %s %s\n", $id, $name, $transaction);
    }
    echo "Let's check we are out? \n";
    $statement->close();
} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: I tried this one a second ago. It says no errror, however the mysqli doesn't fetch  a resource.

Comment: probably you just have no data for that transaction! :-)

Comment: When I input a hardcoded "1234V " it still works. It won't pass the variable.

Comment: It printed: Let's check we are in? 1234V  Let's check we are out?

Comment: Good to know. That means your query is executed but result is empty! 
Probably you are connected to wrong database ;-) That happens time to time when you are working with few test DB.

Comment: I checked the database and did a refresh just in case. It is the original problem that the variable isn't passing any results, but a hardcoded string returns the full results.

Comment: There is no proof to what you are saying. When you hardcode - do you hardcode it in the php script? I guess no, you do that in phpMyAdmin. So to confirm you can change query request in php to `$trans = "SELECT id, name, transaction FROM \`name\`";` and comment out `bind_param` line. So that will return all records you have. Lets try to get it without being filtered.

Comment: I did a cut and paste from PHP: mysqli_stmt::bind_result just to triple check. The code is solid and the databases are right so there must be something wrong with my XAMPP.